# How would I add two if statemenst as a process being open?

Tags: c#, if-statement, checkbox

The title might not make sense so I'll explain it more.

```
if (checkbox1.Checked && (RobloxPlayerBeta.exe is open)
{
   api.Launch;
}
```

I want to make it so that the api launches if the checkbox is checked and the process is open.

Comment: [Process.GetProcesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.8) should help you to complete your if

Answer (score 0):

Making a function to see if a process is active, is pretty straight forward. I have made a small example to show you.

Dont forget to use the following import:

> using System.Diagnostics;

This is the function i'm using:

```
public bool IsProcessOpen(string name)
    {
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(name);  ///Get the process by a name

        if(p.Length == 0) /// if the length of the array is 0, then it means its not running.
        {
            return false;
        }
        else /// if its other then 0 it means its its running.
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I'm checking the answer with a simple button click on a Windows Forms application. I'm using the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(IsProcessOpen(textBox1.Text).ToString());

        ///To test this function, you can try this by changing "textBox1.Text" to "cmd"
        ///If cmd is not opened, it will return false,
        ///If cmd is running, it will return True. You can also do this with other processes. For example Chrome
    }
```

If you decide to copy this function, you're if statement should look something like this:

```
if (checkbox1.Checked == true && IsProcessOpen(RobloxPlayerBeta) == true)
    {
        api.Launch;
    }
```

Hope this helps you out.

Twan